# What the correct way to create a stub using minitest?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

I'm having issues creating a stub for the tests I'm running using `minitest (4.7.0)`. I've tried the following from what I've researched from previous SO questions and it doesn't work:

**test/model/book_test.rb**

```
Book.stub :title, "War and Peace" do
  book = Book.new
  book.title.must_equal "War and Peace"
end
```

**error**

```
NameError: undefined method 'title' for `Book'
```

**app/models/book.rb**

```
class Book  
 #I tried adding the following according to the github readme but it doesn't work:
 #def title.fake_method
 #end
end
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to stub?  What is the behavior you are after?  There are a few things wrong with the above, but I'm not entirely clear on what your goal is.

Comment: The above is an example I used to learn how stubs work. What I want to do is create a stub of the `title` method in the `Book` class to use for testing.  I currently haven't created the `title` method yet so I just need a fake one for testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What/why you're trying to stub in your example doesn't make perfect sense to me, however the below will work and seems to cover the test that you're after.

```
require 'minitest/autorun'

class StubbedBook
  def title
    "War and Peace"
  end
end

class BookTest < MiniTest::Unit::TestCase
  def test_title_is_war_and_peace
    book = StubbedBook.new
    assert_equal book.title, "War and Peace"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO this would be an example of a good place for a factory not a stub.

## assuming Rails 3.2, ruby 1.9, and bundler

Add the factory-girl-rails gem to your Gemfile.

Create the factory:

```
# test/factories/book_factory.rb
FactoryGirl.define do 
  factory :book do 
    title "book title"
  end
end
```

In your before action (or setup) in your unit test.

```
before do 
  @book = FactoryGirl.build(:book)
end
```

Or if you want a custom title:

```
before do 
  @book = FactoryGirl.build(:book, title: "random title")
end
```

Then you can use this instance variable in your test.

Note you can just leverage the FactoryGirl.(build/create) in your individual test too if you prefer. Also if you do the before task its good practice to delete what you created with an after (or teardown) test.